# Implement GStreamer pipeline using UDp socket @command line

Tags: udp, gstreamer-1.0

I want to tranfer the .mp4 file from one terminal to another terminal using Gstreamer pipeline.
first I have test using videotestsrc

```
@server side gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc  pattern=ball ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720 ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink name=sink host=localhost port=34400 sync=false async=false
```

```
@client gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=34400 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)JPEG, payload=(int)26" ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! filesink location=a.mp4
```

but I want read .mp4 file from local directory so I have used following command

```
Server: $gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location =<file_path/>video_test.mp4 ! qtdemux ! video/x-h264 ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=9001
```

```
@client: $gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=9001 caps = "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96" ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! filesink location=a.mp4
```

but i am unable to capture @ client side because a.mp4 file contains 0 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

@server : gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=//video_test.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demux demux. ! h264parse config-interval=10 ! queue ! mux. mpegtsmux name=mux ! rtpmp2tpay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5002  demux. ! aacparse ! queue ! mux.

@client :gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5002 caps="application/x-rtp" ! rtpmp2tdepay ! tsparse !  filesink location=x.mp4

Its working fine for me.